# starting rethinkdb in commandline doesn't coming back to shell prompt

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript, rethinkdb-python, rethinkdb-ruby

I need to change the server_name of a running rethinkdb instance. I have stopped the server and update the /etc/rethinkdb/instances.d/default.conf file and then removed the metadata & rethinkdb_data from /var/lib/rethinkdb/default/data location.  Finally when i executed the rethinkdb --config-file /etc/rethinkdb/instance.d/default.conf it shows that server is ready but didn't came back to bash shell prompt.

Can someone clarify on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean the problem was happening only after you made changes in the server name?  Was that working before?

Answer (score 0):

To start the `rethinkdb` daemon in the background, use:

```
/etc/init.d/rethinkdb start
```

It will automatically read the configuration file in `/etc/rethinkdb/instance.d/default.conf`